# Remove elements from collection while iterating

Tags: java, collections, iteration

AFAIK, there are two approaches:

1. Iterate over a copy of the collection
2. Use the iterator of the actual collection

For instance,

```
List<Foo> fooListCopy = new ArrayList<Foo>(fooList);
for(Foo foo : fooListCopy){
    // modify actual fooList
}
```

and

```
Iterator<Foo> itr = fooList.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
    // modify actual fooList using itr.remove()
}
```

Are there any reasons to prefer one approach over the other (e.g. preferring the first approach for the simple reason of readability)?

Comment: Just curious, why do you create a copy of foolist rather than just looping through foolist in the first example?

Comment: @Haz, So I only have to loop once.

Comment: Note: prefer 'for' over 'while' also with iterators to limit the scope of the variable: 
for(Iterator<Foo> itr = fooList.iterator(); itr.hasNext();){}

Comment: I didn't know `while` had different scoping rules than `for`

Comment: In a more complex situation you might have a case where `fooList` is an instance variable and you call a method during the loop that ends up calling another method in the same class that does `fooList.remove(obj)`. Have seen this happen. In which case copying the list is safest.

Comment: @AlexanderMills while doesn't have a different scope rule. It's just that in case of while, Iterator is being declared outside the loop itself and so it will have a broader scope, even though it is just being used inside loop.

Comment: Since you've accepted the answer you've accepted you probably had an XY problem, since that answer (like a few other here) doesn't actually remove during iteration. And the answer to your nominal question is quite obvious if you think a bit about it: immediately visible effect vs delayed/deferred deletion. It's not just a matter of "style" or "readability".

Answer (score 623, accepted):

Let me give a few examples with some alternatives to avoid a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Suppose we have the following collection of books

```
List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
books.add(new Book(new ISBN("0-201-63361-2")));
books.add(new Book(new ISBN("0-201-63361-3")));
books.add(new Book(new ISBN("0-201-63361-4")));
```

**Collect and Remove**

The first technique consists in collecting all the objects that we want to delete (e.g. using an enhanced for loop) and after we finish iterating, we remove all found objects.

```
ISBN isbn = new ISBN("0-201-63361-2");
List<Book> found = new ArrayList<Book>();
for(Book book : books){
    if(book.getIsbn().equals(isbn)){
        found.add(book);
    }
}
books.removeAll(found);
```

This is supposing that the operation you want to do is "delete".

If you want to "add" this approach would also work, but I would assume you would iterate over a different collection to determine what elements you want to add to a second collection and then issue an `addAll` method at the end.

**Using ListIterator**

If you are working with lists, another technique consists in using a `ListIterator` which has support for removal and addition of items during the iteration itself.

```
ListIterator<Book> iter = books.listIterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    if(iter.next().getIsbn().equals(isbn)){
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Again, I used the "remove" method in the example above which is what your question seemed to imply, but you may also use its `add` method to add new elements during iteration.

**Using JDK >= 8**

For those working with Java 8 or superior versions, there are a couple of other techniques you could use to take advantage of it.

You could use the new `removeIf` method in the `Collection` base class:

```
ISBN other = new ISBN("0-201-63361-2");
books.removeIf(b -> b.getIsbn().equals(other));
```

Or use the new stream API:

```
ISBN other = new ISBN("0-201-63361-2");
List<Book> filtered = books.stream()
                           .filter(b -> b.getIsbn().equals(other))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In this last case, to filter elements out of a collection, you reassign the original reference to the filtered collection (i.e. `books = filtered`) or used the filtered collection to `removeAll` the found elements from the original collection (i.e. `books.removeAll(filtered)`).

**Use Sublist or Subset**

There are other alternatives as well. If the list is sorted, and you want to remove consecutive elements you can create a sublist and then clear it:

```
books.subList(0,5).clear();
```

Since the sublist is backed by the original list this would be an efficient way of removing this subcollection of elements.

Something similar could be achieved with sorted sets using `NavigableSet.subSet` method, or any of the slicing methods offered there.

**Considerations:**

What method you use might depend on what you are intending to do

- The collect and `removeAl` technique works with any Collection (Collection, List, Set, etc).
- The `ListIterator` technique obviously only works with lists, provided that their given `ListIterator` implementation offers support for add and remove operations.
- The `Iterator` approach would work with any type of collection, but it only supports remove operations.
- With the `ListIterator`/`Iterator` approach the obvious advantage is not having to copy anything since we remove as we iterate. So, this is very efficient.
- The JDK 8 streams example don't actually removed anything, but looked for the desired elements, and then we replaced the original collection reference with the new one, and let the old one be garbage collected. So, we iterate only once over the collection and that would be efficient.
- In the collect and `removeAll` approach the disadvantage is that we have to iterate twice. First we iterate in the foor-loop looking for an object that matches our removal criteria, and once we have found it, we ask to remove it from the original collection, which would imply a second iteration work to look for this item in order to remove it.
- I think it is worth mentioning that the remove method of the `Iterator` interface is marked as "optional" in Javadocs, which means that there could be `Iterator` implementations that throw `UnsupportedOperationException` if we invoke the remove method. As such, I'd say this approach is less safe than others if we cannot guarantee the iterator support for removal of elements.

Comment: In your paragraph about JDK8 Streams you mention to `removeAll(filtered)`. A shortcut for that would be `removeIf(b -> b.getIsbn().equals(other))`

Comment: What's the diff between Iterator and ListIterator?

Comment: Haven't considered removeIf, but it was the answer to my prayers. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderMills and any others with the same question – [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html) extends `Iterator` and provides more functionality: `add` and `set`, in addition to `remove`; iterate indices instead of elements; and ability to iterate in both directions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me to implement this solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24182902/how-to-remove-all-key-and-its-value-of-a-particular-keyname-from-json-stringwit/70104599#70104599 .

Answer (score 48):

Old Timer Favorite (it still works):

```
List<String> list;

for(int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) 
{
        if(list.get(i).contains("bad"))
        {
                list.remove(i);
        }
}
```

Benefits:

1. It only iterates over the list *once*
2. No extra objects created, or other unneeded complexity
3. No problems with trying to use the index of a removed item, because... well, think about it!

Comment: Sometimes it is the only working solution.

Comment: At first glance you may miss it, but the secret is to traverse the list backwards.
This prevents that each removal, changes the index of future potential removals.

Comment: I would actually prefer to iterate from the beginning over the list, remove the item, and then decrement the counter. This has much better readability in my opinion. So just use: `for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {...remove(i); i--;...}`

Comment: this would be not working if there are more items to remove, and if they are one riht behind other. To fix this, you need to `i--` after the `list.remove(i);` or the backwards thing. Lookin to other replies ere, if yo need to remove more items after one condition, you have to stuck with improvrf this one

Comment: @maxeh iterating the list in forward order as you suggest will call list.size() once for each item in the list, whereas iterating in reverse order only calls list.size() once.  Also, your approach will decrement i, and then immediately increment it again every time it finds a match.  The logic of the decrement followed by increment is non-intuitive and potentially error prone when the next person comes to inspect the code.

Comment: @SheblaTsama The only working solution worked for me. appreciate it.

Comment: @maxeh thanks for the solution. Although as Shebla Tsama mentioned that this could be confusing, I do want to point out the situations that backward iteration may not work. For example, you have multiple bad items to remove, but every time there is a capacity (dynamically determined) of how many items you can remove, and the item at the beginning higher priority.

Answer (score 21):

In Java 8, there is another approach. [Collection#removeIf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-)

eg:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);

list.removeIf(i -> i > 2);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question of the OP, there is no iteration here

Comment: @UriLoya it's also likely that this question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) hence this answer.

Answer (score 18):

> Are there any reasons to prefer one approach over the other

The first approach will work, but has the obvious overhead of copying the list.

The second approach will not work because many containers don't permit modification during iteration. [This includes `ArrayList`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184883/concurrentmodificationexception-for-arraylist).

If the only modification is to remove the current element, you can make the second approach work by using [`itr.remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) (that is, use the *iterator*'s `remove()` method, not the *container*'s). **This would be my preferred method for iterators that support `remove()`.**

Comment: Oops, sorry...it is implied that I would use the iterator's remove method, not the container's. And how much overhead does copying the list create? It can't be much and since it's scoped to a method, it should be garbage collected rather quickly. See edit..

Comment: @aix I think it is worth mentioning the the remove method of the `Iterator` interface is marked as optional in Javadocs, which means that there could be Iterator implementations that may throw `UnsupportedOperationException`. As such, I'd say this approach is less safe than the first one. Depending on the implementations intended to be used, the first approach could be more suitable.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo `remove()` on the original collection itself may also throw `UnsupportedOperationException`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove(java.lang.Object).  The Java container interfaces are, sadly, defined to be extremely unreliable (defeating the point of the interface, honestly).  If you don't know the exact implementation that will be used at runtime, it's better to do things in an immutable way -- e.g., use the Java 8+ Streams API to filter the elements down and collect them into a new container, then entirely replace the old one with it.

Answer (score 8):

Only second approach will work. You can modify collection during iteration using `iterator.remove()` only. All other attempts will cause `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: The first attempt iterates on a copy, meaning he can modify the original.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do the second, because even if you use the `remove()` method on [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), [you'll get an Exception thrown](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#iterator%28%29).

Personally, I would prefer the first for all `Collection` instances, despite the additional overheard of creating the new `Collection`, I find it less prone to error during edit by other developers. On some Collection implementations, the Iterator `remove()` is supported, on other it isn't. You can read more in the docs for [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

The third alternative, is to create a new `Collection`, iterate over the original, and add all the members of the first `Collection` to the second `Collection` that are *not* up for deletion. Depending on the size of the `Collection` and the number of deletes, this could  significantly save on memory, when compared to the first approach.

Comment: Actually the java docs on this are really confusing. "Iterators allow the caller to remove elements from the underlying collection during the iteration with well-defined semantics." `remove()` itself on the iterator **may *not*** throw that concurrent modification exception (scroll to remove in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) Also "The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress **in any way other than by calling this method**."

Answer (score 0):

I would choose the second as you don't have to do a copy of the memory and the Iterator works faster. So you save memory and time.

Comment: "*Iterator works faster*". Anything to support this claim? Also, the memory footprint of making a copy of a list is very trivial, especially since it'll be scoped within a method and will garbage collected almost immediately.

Comment: In the first approach the disadvantage is that we have to iterate twice. We iterate in the foor-loop looking for an element, and once we find it, we ask to remove it from the original list, which would imply a second iteration work to look for this given item. This would support the claim that, at least in this case, iterator approach should be faster. We have to consider that only the structural space of the collection is the one being created, the objects inside the collections are not being copied. Both collections would keep references to the same objects. When GC happens we cannot tell!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can see this sample; If we think remove odd value from a list:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Predicate<Integer> isOdd = v -> v % 2 == 0;
    List<Integer> listArr = Arrays.asList(5, 7, 90, 11, 55, 60);
    listArr = listArr.stream().filter(isOdd).collect(Collectors.toList());
    listArr.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score -6):

why not this?

```
for( int i = 0; i < Foo.size(); i++ )
{
   if( Foo.get(i).equals( some test ) )
   {
      Foo.remove(i);
   }
}
```

And if it's a map, not a list, you can use keyset()

Comment: This approach has many major disadvantages. First, every time you remove an element, the indexes are reorganized. Therefore, if you remove element 0, then the element 1 becomes the new element 0. If you are going to to this, at least do it backwards to avoid this problem. Second, not all List implementations offer direct access to the elements (as ArrayList does). In a LinkedList this would be tremendously inefficient because every time you issue an `get(i)` you have to visit all nodes until you reach `i`.

Comment: Never considered this as I typically just used it to remove a single item I was looking for. Good to know.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but surely in the if block code after `Foo.remove(i);` you should do `i--;`?

Comment: becouse it's bugged