# How to remove all key and its value of a particular keyname from json string(with children) in java

Tags: java, json, string

I want to remove all key "id" and its value from my json string. Problem is "id" comes at many level in my json string. I am using JSONObject. With JSONObject we can remove "id" at top level only but i need to remove "id" from every level. Please help me

Ex of json string -

```
"{
    "success": {
        "body": {
            "id": 5827,
            "siteName": "RPX",
            "instances": [
                {
                    "instanceId": "i-3a63035e",
                    "name": "prdae-mst21a (iserver)",
                    "state": "running",
                    "publicDnsName": "ec2-54-209-175-118.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
                    "tags": [

                        {
                            "id": 9783,
                            "key": "ktier",
                            "value": "da"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 9782,
                            "key": "Name",
                            "value": "prdae-mst21a (iserver)"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 9781,
                            "key": "kreg",
                            "value": "e"
                        }
                    ],
                    "sshAccessInfo": {
                        "id": 9788,
                        "keyPair": {
                            "id": 6050,
                            "keyName": "Kens key",
                            "status": "UPLOADED",
                            "defaultUser": "root",
                            "passPhrase": "imaginea#@!"
                        },
                        "userName": "imaginea"
                    },
                    "account": {
                        "id": 5857,
                        "accountId": "348713271046",
                        "type": "AWS",
                        "ownerAlias": "348713271046",
                        "regionName": "us-east-1"
                    },
                    "availabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
                    "publicIpAddress": "54.209.175.118",
                    "instanceType": "m2.2xlarge"
                },
                {
                    "instanceId": "i-65ad2346",
                    "name": "prpoe-pap22e cp",
                    "state": "running",
                    "publicDnsName": "ec2-54-86-2-65.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
                    "tags": [
                        {
                            "id": 9755,
                            "key": "kzone",
                            "value": "e"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 9754,
                            "key": "kreg",
                            "value": "e"
                        }
                    ],
                    "sshAccessInfo": {
                        "id": 9756,
                        "keyPair": {
                            "id": 5895,
                            "keyName": "rpxprod-rightscale",
                            "status": "UPLOADED",
                            "defaultUser": "ubuntu",
                            "passPhrase": "imaginea#@!"
                        },
                        "userName": "imaginea"
                    },
                    "account": {
                        "id": 5857,
                        "accountId": "348713271046",
                        "type": "AWS",
                        "ownerAlias": "348713271046",
                        "regionName": "us-east-1"
                    },
                    "availabilityZone": "us-east-1e",
                    "publicIpAddress": "54.86.2.65",
                    "instanceType": "m1.large"
                }  ],
            "filters": [
                {
                    "id": 5828,
                    "accountInfo": {
                        "id": 5829,
                        "type": "AWS",
                        "regionName": "us-east-1"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "loadBalancers": [
                {
                    "id": 5855,
                    "name": "st-pgpool-cp",
                    "vpcId": "vpc-865c68ee",
                    "instanceIds": [
                        "i-b81511eb"
                    ],
                    "availabilityZones": [
                        "us-east-1e"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 5850,
                    "name": "pr-pgpool-cp",
                    "vpcId": "vpc-865c68ee",
                    "instanceIds": [
                        "i-ed262988"
                    ],
                    "availabilityZones": [
                        "us-east-1d"
                    ]
                }
                {
                    "id": 5844,
                    "name": "qa2-api",
                    "vpcId": "vpc-865c68ee",
                    "instanceIds": [
                        "i-63687842"
                    ],
                    "availabilityZones": [
                        "us-east-1a"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 5830,
                    "name": "prod-portal-https-v31",
                    "vpcId": "vpc-865c68ee",
                    "instanceIds": [
                        "i-97509bfa",
                        "i-660f0408"
                    ],
                    "availabilityZones": [
                        "us-east-1e",
                        "us-east-1d"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}"
```

I want to remove `id` from `body`, `instances`, `sshAccessInfo`, `filters`, `loadBalancer` etc. Please provide a decent way to to this.

Comment: Are you generating this JSON or just receiving it?

Comment: How about recursive traversing if you are already able to remove one key-value-pair?

Comment: Hello cy3er- I am receiving this Json as String parameter.

Comment: Hello Smutje - dont know how to recursively traverse because this json is dynamic. next time it may contain "instances" and "siteName" only. If i am getting you wrong then plz give an ex with the above string.let say the json string is stored in String objStr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not very nice, but if it can be **really** dynamic then you could use a regexp and `replaceAll()` to remove the desired key-values from the JSON string before parsing anything:

```
json = json.replaceAll("\"" + prop + "\"[ ]*:[^,}\\]]*[,]?", "")
```

In your case `String prop = "id"`.

Comment: will this replace id's value with ""  as well ?

Comment: CAUTION: This can create invalid JSON for **generated** JSON strings (strings with escaped quotation marks \") 
If you have an Array in your JSON, that contains nested Json Objects, this will return invalid JSON! e.g. 
{ "array": [{ "e": {"pl": "ALTITUDE", "e": 0.5}}, 2]}
will create {"array": [{ }},2]}

Comment: It worked for me with the addition at the next line of the command:
    json = json.replace(",}","}");

Answer (score 3):

My answer is the same as @frank.zheng except I threw in an if statement that checks if array children are objects before it tries to recurse back into the function.

```
public static void removeJSONField(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException{
    obj.remove("id");

    Iterator<String> it = obj.keys();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        String key = it.next();
        Object childObj = obj.get(key);
        if(childObj instanceof JSONArray){
            JSONArray arrayChildObjs =((JSONArray)childObj);
            int size = arrayChildObjs.length();
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                if (arrayChildObjs.get(i) instanceof JSONObject){
                    removeJSONField(arrayChildObjs.getJSONObject(i));
                }
            }
        }
        if(childObj instanceof JSONObject){
            removeJSONField(((JSONObject) childObj));

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I used this solution to implement mine. See my answer posted as one of the solutions. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Please test the following code snippet. It should meet you well

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jsonStr ="{'id':'2839','body':{'id':'22',objs:[{id:1},{id:2}]}}";
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        removeJSONField(obj);

        System.out.println(obj);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void removeJSONField(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException{
    obj.remove("id");

    Iterator<String> it = obj.keys();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        String key = it.next();
        Object childObj = obj.get(key);
        if(childObj instanceof JSONArray){
            JSONArray arrayChildObjs =((JSONArray)childObj);
            int size = arrayChildObjs.length();
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                removeJSONField(arrayChildObjs.getJSONObject(i));
            }
        }
        if(childObj instanceof JSONObject){
            removeJSONField(((JSONObject) childObj));

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't be very useful to a new developer without knowing which JSON library it uses.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my day. @frank

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 is to parse your JSON string into a set of objects. There are several JSON libraries for java, and they're not very difficult to use. Using [javax.json](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/index.html?javax/json/package-summary.html) for example, you'd do the following:

1. Create a `StringReader` or `ByteArrayInputStream` which references your JSON string.
2. Call `Json.createReader()` to get a JSON reader.
3. Call `JSONReader.read()` or `JSONReader.readObject()` to parse the string into a set of JSON objects.
4. Modify your JSON objects as needed.
5. Create a JSON writer and convert the JSON objects back into a string, if you need it that way.

Other JSON libraries would follow a similar process, though their specific class names might be different.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to remove all keys matching a given prefix:

```
void removeKeysWithPrefix(JSONObject obj, String prefix) {
    Iterator<String> itr;
    String theKey="*something*from*nothing*";
    Object theObj;
    JSONArray theItems;
    JSONObject theItem;
    int size;
    itr = obj.keys();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        theKey = itr.next();
        theObj = obj.get(theKey);
        if (theKey.startsWith(prefix)) {
            itr.remove();
        } else
        if (theObj instanceof JSONArray) {
            theItems = ((JSONArray)theObj);
            size = theItems.length();
            for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
                if (theItems.get(i) instanceof JSONObject) {
                    theItem = theItems.getJSONObject(i);
                    removeKeysWithPrefix(theItem, prefix);
                }
            }
        } else
        if (theObj instanceof JSONObject) {
            removeKeysWithPrefix( ((JSONObject)theObj), prefix);
        }
    }
}
```