# Java , Removing object from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I have ClassA which has a static ArrayList of Objects

```
public static ArrayList<Meteorit> meteorits = new ArrayList<Meteorit>();
```

Now I want to remove an object from this list like this

```
ClassA.meteorits.remove(this);
```

This is written in Meteorit class . But it throws exception when I want to use the objects in the ArrayList .

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

I used Iterator to remove objects from ArrayList but now I dont have an idea how to use it in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove elements from collection while iterating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431981/remove-elements-from-collection-while-iterating)

Comment: Why is the ArrayList `static`? I suggest to do it exactly like how `observer` design pattern did. First, make a method inside `ClassA` call it `public removeMetorit(Meteorit meteorit)` and use it from wherever exept the `Meteorit` class.

Comment: Also, you are calling the `remove` method from inside the object to be removed and this is illegal.

Comment: I want the meteorite to remove itself from the list, I don't think it's illegal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because some thread is actually viewing this list in a for each loop, maybe you are trying to remove elements of this list in the body of for-each? You can't remove elements in for-each, but you can in iterator loops:

You can use iterator instead of for each to remove and view the elements of the list like this:

```
public static ArrayList<Meteorit> meteorits = new ArrayList<Meteorit>();

Iterator<Meteorit> itr = meteorits.iterator();

while (itr.hasNext()) {
       if (itr.next()==this) {
          itr.remove();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using an iterator; you need to use the iterator to remove items from a list using this:

```
iterator.remove();
```

which from the Java Docs says:

> Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by this iterator.

Removing a item from the list by any other means will result in the ConcurrentModificationException you are seeing.

Comment: I know this , but I need the way how to use it in this case.

Comment: If you could supply more snippets of your code in your question in order to an appropriate answer; otherwise it is hard to apply this knowledge to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to use iterator to avoid such concurrent modification:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String string = iterator.next();
    if (string.isEmpty()) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

For more details, please check out this post:

[Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-list-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-removing)

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterator<Integer> itr = yourlist.iterator();

// remove all even numbers
while (itr.hasNext()) {
       itr.remove();
}
```

this must work for you, other way to work around this issue is to use  CopyOnWriteArrayList hopefully it help.