# Returning an Iterator from method

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, iterator

I can't seem to print the elements in the `Iterator` when returned from the method `removeTwos()`. I am trying to remove elements from the list that only has two characters.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // write your code here
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("hi");
        list.add("what");
        list.add("who");
        list.add("ok");

        System.out.println(removeTwos(list));
    }

    public static String removeTwos(List<String> stringList) {

        Iterator<String> itr = stringList.iterator();
        for(int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
            if(itr.hasNext() && itr.next().length() == 2) {
                itr.remove();
                System.out.println(itr.toString());
            }
        }
        return itr.toString();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "display the iterator"?  The `Iterator` object itself?  Something else?  What do you expect to see?

Comment: Why would you `Iterator#toString()` ???

Comment: Yes to print @LAD

Comment: You don't need to return anything. You remove the elements from the list. Just print the list thereafter: `System.out.println(list);`

Comment: also it would be better to not use a for loop and an iterator. more like `while(itr.hasNext{}){ String s = itr.next() work with s}`

Comment: @Antoniosss, I just want to print it

Comment: itr.toString() returns "Iterator@{hashcode}"  not the list or the element.  do you want the method to return the modified list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is: you don't need an `Iterator` at all for what you're trying to do. You can just search each item in the list one by one with the methods of the list.

Try this code out and see if it works for you:

```
public class JavaApplication255 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("hi");
        list.add("what");
        list.add("who");
        list.add("ok");

        removeTwos(list);
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    public static void removeTwos(List<String> stringList){

        for(int i = stringList.size() - 1; i >= 0 ; i--){
            String string = stringList.get(i);

            if (string.length() == 2){
                stringList.remove(string);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Index-looping and removing at the same time should be done from back to start.

Comment: You're right that he doesn't need to use an `Iterator` for this problem. `Iterator` can be used as well - it's just personal preference.

Comment: Definitely. It's just nicer to keep things simple. Thanks for the edit btw, have a nice day !

Answer (score 1):

To use an `Iterator` for this problem, you can edit your `removeTwos` method to something like this:

```
public static String removeTwos(List<String> stringList) {

    Iterator<String> itr = stringList.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        String value = itr.next();
        if (value.length() == 2) {
            System.out.println(value);
            itr.remove();
        }
    }

    return stringList.toString();
}
```

When using an `Iterator`, it is safe to remove elements from the list while looping through it. [Here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10432084/6214491) that demonstrates that it's safe.

Comment: what is the for loop for?what do we need 'i' for?

Answer (score 1):

using stream and filter is easy 1 liner unless you need to use iter.

```
List<String> noTwos = list.stream().filter(s-> s.length() != 2).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `for(int idx..)` loop and also remove items you should iterate from end to start.

```
for(int idx=stringList.size()-1; idx>=0; idx--){
   String val = stringList.get(idx);
   if (val.length()==2)
      stringList.remove(idx);
}
...later if you want to print a list..
for(int idx=0; idx<stringList.size(); idx++) {
   System.out.println( String.format("%d:%s", idx, stringList.get(idx)) );
```

Comment: How would I be able to display it in main? Or are we not supposed to use iterators to print or displaY?

Comment: See my answer; i put a loop and sysout print example. You don't need to return a list object from the subroutine as you are in-place modifying the list content.

Answer (score 0):

I like using `for` loops with iterators:

```
public static void removeTwos(List<String> stringList) 
{
    for (Iterator<String> itr = stringList.iterator(); itr.hasNext();)
        if (itr.next().length() == 2) itr.remove();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] arr = { "hi", "what", "who", "ok" };
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
    removeTwos(list);
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Output:

```
[what, who]
```

Comment: this is acceptable as you are using the iterator as part of the control. using for i;i<x:i++) when you don't use i. is pointless

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String removeTwos(List<String> stringList){
    return stringList.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.length() != 2)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

return:

> what, who