# How would you write a "pure" function that removes an element from a List?

Tags: java, functional-programming, pure-function

In Java (or any similar language) how would you write a [Pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) (or method) that removes an element from a list.

If the element is in the list, we simply return a new (ideally immutable) list containing all the elements of the input list, minus the element we removed.

But how would you handle the case where the element isn't found in the list?

Let's assume the method receives 2 parameters, the `list` and the `element` to remove:

```
public SOMETHING remove(final List<String> list, final String element){
    // Copy the input list and remove the first occurrence of 'element', if I find it.
    // 
    // if I don't find it ... do something clever here ...
}
```

If I call this method, and `element` is not contained inside `list`:

- Throwing an exception would presumably make method "impure" (?)
- Modifying the input list and returning a boolean (similar to [List#remove()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object))) would presumable make the method "impure" (modifying the input would be a side-effect)
- Returning the input as output would seem unintuitive to me if I was calling this method.
- return an `Optional.of(listCopy)` (EDIT: added to my question after posting it)
- Any other ideas ?

#### EDIT

I should have mentioned that I only want to remove the first occurrence of `element`, so if the input `list` has multiple occurrences of `element`, I don't want to remove them all with a sigle call to my remove() method (e.g. using `stream().filter()`). I just edited the comment in my code example to reflect this. However, this is not fully relevant to my question, as my main question revolves around how to make the method intuitive to use AND remain "pure".

#### EDIT 2

I added an additional idea to the above suggestions. Returning `Optional.of(listCopy)` seems like the most elegant solution of the proposed solutions so far. It forces the caller to check if the requested operation was successful or not, AND (if it was successful), it returns a new list, thereby not modifying the original input list. If the operation was not successful (`element` wasn't found inside `list`), the method returns `Optional.empty()`. It seems to me this would also fulfil the below mentioned **referential integrity**.

Comment: There is similar question with answers: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431981/remove-elements-from-collection-while-iterating)

Comment: "Its return value is the same for the same arguments" - Would you interpret this as the same type, a reference to the same object, or the same reference that was passed in? I'm sure all choices could be argued.

Comment: @AndrzejSydor, thanks for the suggestions, but that's not at all what I was asking!

Comment: @JacobG. I think the only "pure programming" solution would be to return a new list of the same type as the input list. Bug again, how do we handle the case where the element to be removed is not found in the list...

Answer (score 5):

Going through the points you mentioned:

1. Throwing an exception would presumably make method "impure" (?)

   - This is an implementation decision, if you want to return the same list or throw an exception. as for 'pure function' - as long as you're consistent and the same input yields the same result (or exception), you're good
2. Modifying the input list and returning a boolean (similar to List#remove()) would presumable make the method "impure" (modifying the input would be a side-effect)

   - this will make it non pure functional, as you'll have a side effect
3. Returning the input as output would seem unintuitive to me if I was calling this method.

   - don't see any problem with that actually. again, your call if it's a valid scenario or not. in terms of 'pure function', you're ok here

as for implementation, I think stream is the simplest, and returns new list so you're ok in terms of purity

```
return list.stream()
 .filter(e -> !e.equals(element))
 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
public List<String> remove(final List<String> list, final String element) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(list);
    result.remove(element);
    return result;
}
```

From the Wikipedia, it must:

- have the same return for the same inputs - can't see any reason why this wouldn't be true here, no randoms, no IO, etc
- be stateless - only parameters are dealt with in this function. May as well make it `static`

EDIT (just saw comment about returning a new list each time)

If you are trying to achieve functional-style code in Java, then the fact that it is a new list causes problems. You are probably referring to a property called **referential transparency**. To summarise, a value has referential transparency if  it can be replaced with a reference to itself, and vice versa, without changing the semantics of a program. Java does not really support this, and this is one of the reasons Java is not truly functional.

In Haskell, (almost) all expressions have referential transparency, i.e. a list `[1, 2, 3, 4]` is not just equivalent to another list `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, it is **the same thing**. This is similar to how in maths, `7` is the same thing as `7`, it doesn't make sense to say "that `7` isn't the same `7` that I have in this equation".

Going back to Java, you require that subsequent calls return the same output. It is therefore up to you to define what you mean by "same". In the functional world, this is usually determined by values, (i.e. using `Arrays.equals()`). However, if you want to use `==` (i.e. 2 lists are equal if and only if they occupy the same location in memory), the functional style is probably not what you want.

Hope that clears it up.

Comment: This does not return the same value for a specific input, as a different `ArrayList` is created every time, regardless of its contents.

Comment: @JacobG if you’re requiring reference equality, it is simply impossible. You’d need to keep state to map inputs to previous outputs. Plus, it would also mean that if you add/remove items to/from the input list between calls, you’d magically return the same result as before but with corrected contents.

Answer (score 3):

Any mutation to the existing list fails "Property 1" per Wikipedia.

> Its evaluation has no side effects (no mutation of local static variables, non-local variables, mutable reference arguments or I/O streams).

Your only real hope here is to return a *new* `List` with all of the elements copied over, *except* the one that you want to remove.

```
public List<String> remove(final List<String> list, final String element) {
    return list.stream()
                   .filter(e -> !Objects.equals(e, element))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This also handles the "element not in list" scenario since you get back a *new* list instance with the same elements as the old one.  Effectively, if the state of your data doesn't change, then there's no real harm in returning the same state.

Bear in mind, though - this is actually quite expensive and/or wasteful, and wouldn't really be a valuable exercise with collections.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a new `List` and loop through the input array, adding every element that wasn't `element`, then return the new list

Comment: How would that satisfy "Its return value is the same for the same arguments" if you were returning a new `List` every time, regardless if they contained the same elements?

Comment: Because the list you return has the same values if you call it with the same args multiple times

Comment: Yes, but `remove(list, element) == remove(list, element)` would return `false`.

Comment: You would use List's `equals` function https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: I agree with @MarcSlothEastman for the happy case that the `element` to be removed is actually contained inside the input list. But again, what do we do if the element isn't to be found inside the input list ?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, personally I would return the new one just to make the function simpler @Chris

Answer (score 0):

For example, using [ListIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html):

```
ListIterator<Book> iter = books.listIterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    if(iter.next().getIsbn().equals(isbn)){
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: No :-) 
(if you modify the original list, it's no longer a "pure function")