# Removing items from a list while iterating over it

Tags: java, collections, iterator, concurrentmodification

I've seen many questions regarding this topics but none of the answers that really quite my usecase (Unless I've interpreted it wrong.). Is it possible to remove an item from a list while an iterator is iterating over it?

What I'm trying to achieve is having a queue with an audioplayer. The iterator iterates over the queue and blocks while playing the song. Songs can be added to or deleted from the queue while it is already playing.

I've tried the above idea and received an exception `ConcurrentModificationException` .
I've also read that it's a bad practice to mutate a collection while an iterator is iterating over it. I'm hoping someone can point me into the right direction on how to properly mutate a list from a method call while iterating over it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove elements from collection while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431981/remove-elements-from-collection-while-iterating)

Comment: You can use a temp list and while iterating add only those values which are desired , and later assign this temp list to original list

Comment: @Adnan But the iterator doesn't know if the value is desired until it reaches it. And it only goes to a next/previous when requested or when the 'audio' is done playing. So until the iterator reaches the object that is 'marked for removal' it's still in the list.

Comment: Oh nevermind question got closed because someone thought it's a duplicate except that it's not.

Comment: I would suggest writing this as a custom class, without implementing `Iterable` or `Iterator`. Store the songs in an ArrayList and keep track of the index of the currently-playing song; to get the next one, increment that index and return the song at the new index. When you add or remove a song, update the index accordingly. Using `Iterable`/`Iterator` makes it too complicated, because it's the main class which knows how to update the indices, not the iterator(s) themselves; and it seems you don't need to have multiple concurrent iterators over the same list.

Comment: @kaya3 I was already writing [a similar approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60174756/2711488), but thanks to `AbstractList` which has all the methods and features re-routed through a few methods, it’s possible to support the entire Collection API and still update the index correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is not to maintain the currently playing song resp. the next song to play via an `Iterator`. Instead, you can create a specialized list which knows how to adapt this pointer on modifications.

Such a class could look like

```
class SongList extends AbstractList<Song> implements RandomAccess {
    final List<Song> backend = new ArrayList<>();
    int currentSong = -1;

    SongList() {}
    SongList(Collection<? extends Song> c) {
        backend.addAll(c);
    }
    // mandatory query methods

    @Override public int size() {
        return backend.size();
    }
    @Override public Song get(int index) {
        return backend.get(index);
    }

    // the "iterator"
    public Song nextSong() {
        if(++currentSong < size()) {
            return get(currentSong);
        }
        currentSong = -1;
        return null;
    }

    // modifying methods, which will adapt the pointer

    @Override public void add(int index, Song element) {
        backend.add(index, element);
        if(index <= currentSong) currentSong++;
    }
    @Override public Song remove(int index) {
        final Song removed = backend.remove(index);
        if(index <= currentSong) currentSong--;
        return removed;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends Song> c) {
        int old = size();
        backend.addAll(index, c);
        if(index <= currentSong) currentSong += size() - old;
        return true;
    }

    @Override protected void removeRange(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        backend.subList(fromIndex, toIndex).clear();
        if(fromIndex <= currentSong)
            currentSong = Math.max(fromIndex - 1, currentSong - toIndex + fromIndex);
    }

    // this will not change the pointer

    @Override public Song set(int index, Song element) {
        return backend.set(index, element);
    }

    // query methods overridden for performance

    @Override public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return backend.contains(o);
    }
    @Override public int indexOf(Object o) {
        return backend.indexOf(o);
    }
    @Override public Spliterator<Song> spliterator() {
        return backend.spliterator();
    }
    @Override public void forEach(Consumer<? super Song> action) {
        backend.forEach(action);
    }
    @Override public Object[] toArray() {
        return backend.toArray();
    }
    @Override public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        return backend.toArray(a);
    }
    @Override public String toString() {
        return backend.toString();
    }
}
```

`AbstractList` is specifically designed to provide the collection operations atop a few methods, so we only need to implement `size()` and `get(int)` to have a readable list and by providing `add(int, Song)`, `remove(int)`, and `set(int, Song)` we did already everything needed to support all modification operations. The other methods are only provided to improve the performance, the inherited methods would also work.

The list supports a single pointer to a current play position, which can be iterated via `nextSong()`. When reaching the end, it will return `null` and reset the pointer, so that the next query will start again. The `add` and `remove` methods will adapt the pointer such that an already played song won’t be played again (unless restarting the entire list).

`set` based modifications do not adapt the pointer, which implies that nothing meaningful will happen when you `sort` the list, some policies are imaginable, but at least when the list has duplicates, no perfect behavior exists. When comparing with other player software, no-one seems to expect perfect behavior when the list is turned up-side-down while playing. At least, there will never be an exception.

Comment: Combined with what I drew out earlier today this has pointed me in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use an `Iterator` and call its `remove()` method:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Iterator<String> i = myList.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    String next = i.next();
    if (some condition) {
        i.remove(); // removes the current element
    }
}
```

Comment: With the caveat that not all lists' iterators support removal.

Comment: I want to edit the list from a method call, not the iterator itself. The iterator should just take the previous/next object when it's done with the current object.