# java.lang.IllegalStateException in iterator.remove()

Tags: java, illegalstateexception

**Rocket** class contains: **canCarry**(Item item)>checks if this item can be carried/ **carry** updates the weight with total weight.

**U2** class is child of Rocket contains: **currentweight**, **maxWeight**=18 tons
Item class contains: name to be shipped & weight.

In the method **loadU2** I am trying to access a list of items and adding it into one rocket until **maxWeight** of that rocket is reached . *For example I have 216 tons of items to carry returning a list of 12 ships.*

It throws me **java.lang.IllegalStateException** error in the line **iterator.remove()**. I do not know how to go about it, but it looks like it is not allowing me to remove the items while iterating.

```
public ArrayList<Rocket> loadU2(ArrayList<Item> loadItems){
    //list of ships
    ArrayList<Rocket> U2Ships = new ArrayList<Rocket>();
    for(Iterator<Item> iterator = loadItems.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {      
        //create a new ship
        Rocket tempShip = new U2();
        Item tempItem = iterator.next();
        //loop over items check if it can be filled then remove the item that was filled.
        while(tempShip.currentWeight<tempShip.weightLimit) {
            if(tempShip.canCarry(tempItem)){
                tempShip.carry(tempItem);
                iterator.remove();
            }           
        }
        U2Ships.add(tempShip);
    }
    return U2Ships;
}   


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.remove(ArrayList.java:980)
    at Simulation.loadU1(Simulation.java:35)
    at Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Simplified example of what the code is doing:
Assuming **maxWeight** for each ship = 11 tons
ArrayList loadItems = [3,5,5,8,1,2,3,5] tons

```
 - Ship[1]=[3,5,1,2]
 - new list to iterate over >> [5,8,3,5]
 - Ship[2]=[5,3]
 - new list to iterate over >> [8,5]
 - Ship[3]=[8]
 - new list to iterate over >> [5]
 - Ship[4]=[5]
```

Comment: You have a `while` loop where you potentially call `iterator.remove()` multiple times. That is not possible, you can call it only once. Once it is "removed" you cannot remove it again, it's already gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, rewrite your code by creating new ArrayList, instead of changing the existing list inside its own iterator:

```
public ArrayList<Rocket> loadU2(ArrayList<Item> loadItems){
    //list of ships
    ArrayList<Rocket> U2Ships = new ArrayList<Rocket>();
    ArrayList<Item> updatedLoadItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
    for(Iterator<Item> iterator = loadItems.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {      
        //create a new ship
        Rocket tempShip = new U2();
        Item tempItem = iterator.next();
        //loop over items check if it can be filled then only leave the load item that was not fully filled.
        boolean addLoadItem = true;
        while(tempShip.currentWeight<tempShip.weightLimit) {
            if(tempShip.canCarry(tempItem)){
                tempShip.carry(tempItem);
                addLoadItem = false;
            }         
        }
        if (addLoadItem) {
          updatedLoadItems.add(tempItem);
        };
        U2Ships.add(tempShip);
    }
    loadItems.removeAll();
    loadItems.addAll(updatedLoadItems);
    return U2Ships;
}
```

This is not the best solution, but to provide a better solution, you need to change the signature of `public ArrayList<Rocket> loadU2(ArrayList<Item> loadItems)`

You can try to improve your code by refactoring it.

**Hint:** right now your **loadU2** method tries to do both things at the same time: change **loadItems** and create **U2Ships**. This is a direct violation of the **single responsibility principle**. Try to imagine the soldier who would try to shoot the gun and throw grenade at the same time! One thing at the time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
while(tempShip.currentWeight<tempShip.weightLimit) {
    if(tempShip.canCarry(tempItem)){
        tempShip.carry(tempItem);
        iterator.remove();
    }           
}
```

You are calling `iterator.remove()` within a loop. If the condition `tempShip.canCarry(tempItem)` holds twice, you call `iterator.remove()` twice, and this is not allowed (the second time, the item is already removed).

I don't know how the method `canCarry` is implemented, but note that if it is the case that `tempShip.currentWeight<tempShip.weightLimit` is true, but `tempShip.canCarry(tempItem)` is false, your loop will run forever.

Answer (score 0):

use listIterator instead of Iterator.

```
ListIterator<Book> iter = books.listIterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    if(iter.next().getIsbn().equals(isbn)){
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

like used here.

[Remove elements from collection while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431981/remove-elements-from-collection-while-iterating)

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<Rocket> loadU2(ArrayList<Item> loadItems){
    //list of ships
    int shipNum=0;
    int itemsloaded=0;
    ArrayList<Rocket> U2Ships = new ArrayList<Rocket>();
    while(!loadItems.isEmpty()) {      
        System.out.println("number of ships created: "+shipNum++);
        //create a new ship
        Rocket tempShip = new U2();
        
        //loop over items check if it can be filled then only leave the load item that was not fully filled.
     
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {  
            Item tempItem = iterator.next();
            if(tempShip.canCarry(tempItem)){
                System.out.println("number of items loaded: "+(itemsloaded++));
                tempShip.carry(tempItem);
                iterator.remove();                                      
             
           } 
        }
        
        U2Ships.add(tempShip);
    }

    return U2Ships;
}
```

Thank you guys for the help, this should fix 2 problems: infinity, and the iterator.remove().

Comment: `iterator.remove()` was no problem, the way you used it was a problem. In fact, your new solution now has a bug *because* you're not using an iterator. Try it out with a list of two items both of which would fit in a single ship, and note how your code creates two ships rather than one. The reason is, that `loadItems.remove(i)` will change the indices of the tail of the list, and therefore skip an item in the next iteration. Using an iterator and `Iterator.remove()` would solve that.