# Object not being removed from array after being found in array list

Tags: java

I have a method to delete an object from an array list based on an attribute of the class called id. When I call it, it finds the correct id then breaks. This is all very new to me

```
    public static void DeleteStudent(ArrayList<Student> Student_Class, String studentid) {
        for(Student student : Student_Class)
            if(student.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(studentid))
                Student_Class.remove(student);
    }
```

error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1013)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:967)
> at StudentProgram.DeleteStudent(StudentProgram.java:39)
> at StudentProgram.main(StudentProgram.java:28)

Comment: Edit your post to show what you mean by "breaks". I assume that is an error message? If so, edit your post and paste the error message there.

Comment: And in general, if you want to remove elements from an `ArrayList` while looping through it, it is better to use an instance of `java.util.Iterator` as opposed to just doing a for-each loop. A for-each loop is just for reading stuff. But if you plan to modify while reading, an `Iterator` is a better choice.

Comment: Ah, `ConcurrentModificationException`. In that case, the other answer covers the solution you need to implement. Let either of us know if the link does not make sense.

Comment: thanks I think this is what I needed but I'll let you know if it goes awry

Comment: Actually, I really dislike the other answer now that I read the link. I am typing up my own.

Comment: Yeah I'm still confused but at least I'm in the ballpark now

Comment: @ThomasHutton, this is because the _for-each_ loop utilizes an _Iterator_.  For example, if you did this with a regular _for-loop_ you would not receive a _ConcurrentModificationException_.  Just modify the conditional statement as the list size changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only use a for-each loop if you are doing READ-ONLY operations on a `Collection` (your `ArrayList` is a `Collection`).

If you want to DELETE while looping, you should use a [`java.util.Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html) instead.

An `Iterator` is easy to use, and your `ArrayList` even gives you a method to fetch an `Iterator`. All you have to do is add an import on the top (`import java.util.Iterator;`), then say `Iterator<Student> iterator = myList.iterator();`.

Here is how it would be done with your code example. Don't forget to include the import at the top of your class.

```java
public static void DeleteStudent(ArrayList<Student> Student_Class, String studentid)
{

    Iterator<Student> iterator = Student_Class.iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {

        Student student = iterator.next();

        if(student.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(studentid))
        {

            iterator.remove(); //removes the most recently fetched student

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you're iterating over the list using a for loop. The trouble comes when you try to remove an object *while* you're still iterating with the for loop. Since the length of the ArrayList changes, you get a concurrent modification error because it's not permissible to edit a collection while simultaneously iterating over it. Look into these resources for more info on how to accomplish what you're trying to do:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10432084/19370127

More info about the exception: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html

Comment: Maybe you meant to send a different link? I don't think this link is actually a relevant one to the question the OP has.

Comment: Ok, that stackoverflow and javadocs links are ok, but your first link is just unhelpful and irrelevant.

Comment: I added another stackoverflow page that's clearer, but the original link works too because the removeAll method of ArrayList performs the function that the OP wants to do, just inline rather than as a for loop

Comment: Granted it's not the official javadocs, so maybe I'll change that once I find the link

Comment: Eh, I guess it's fine. I'll type up my own answer though.

Comment: The collect and remove method worked for me, thanks everybody

Answer (score 1):

ConcurrentModificationException occurs when you perform the following sequence of events:

- You ask a collector for an `iterator()`. (and `for (String foo : collection)` does that).
- You modify the collection directly, such as `collection.remove`.
- You interact with that iterator. For example, by moving on to the next item (which is what looping that for loop would do).

You do that here: You ask for an iterator, remove from the collection, and then interact with the iterator.

iterators support what you want. Replace your code with:

```
var it = studentClass.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  Student student = it.next();
  if (student.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(studentId)) it.remove();
}
```

Here we remove just the same, but... *via the iterator*, which, unlike removing directly on the collection, this means the iterator remains valid.

Comment: thank you for explaining this I didn't quite understand iterators