# Java concurrency (Threads) at ArrayLists. Difference between classic for and foreach

Tags: java, foreach, iterator

I have a question connected with my GalaxyInvaders clone.

What is the difference between `for` and `foreach` iterating through `ArrayList`?

I'm modifying `ArrayLists` (changing variables / removing some objects) using `foreach` loops (I'm blocking sections before doing that using `Semaphores`).

Question is, when I use `foreach` statement, application throws exception.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-39" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
at pl.mosek.MyPanel2$ColissionDetector.run(GUI.java:421)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

When I use classic `for` statement, problem magically dissapears. 
Can somebody explain me why is that?

CODE:

```
@Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            if (ship.getBullets().isEmpty() == false
                    && monsters.isEmpty() == false) {

                semaphoreLock(semaphoreBullet);

                for (Bullet i : ship.getBullets()) {
                    if (i.isDestroyed() != true) {

                        semaphoreLock(semaphoreMonster);

                        for (Enemy j : monsters) {
                            if (i.getBounds()
                                    .intersects(j.getBounds())
                                    &&j.isDestroyed() != true) {
                                i.setDestroyed(true);
                                i.setVisible(false);

                                j.setDestroyed(true);
                                j.setVisible(false);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    semaphoreRelease(semaphoreMonster);
                }
                semaphoreRelease(semaphoreBullet);

            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(25);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

If i switch `foreach` to `for` statments, everything working correctly.

Comment: Could you show us the code which produces that exception?

Comment: In Java iterators (the ArrayList iterator in this case) can not modify the underlying connection. They must change a copy of the collection or iterate over a copy of it - it's part of the abstraction,.

Comment: [Java ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That's quite wrong. See `Iterator#remove`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik fair enough, what I meant was iterating using a `for : ` loop. Removing an element during that is undefined behavior. If you have the actual Iterator you can remove elements. As for the #remove remark - I raise you an UnsupportedOperationException  :P

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Not on `ArrayList` you don't :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a standard for-loop, you access the elements of the list via `get()` and (perhaps) set them via `set()`. These methods cannot detect concurrent modification. However, with a for-each loop, you are actually using an [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) as returned by the list's [`iterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#iterator%28%29) method, which [*does* check for concurrent modification](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#754). Hence the difference.

A for-each loop

```
for (Element e : list) {
    ...
}
```

actually becomes something like:

```
for (Iterator<Element> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    Element e = iter.next();
    ...
}
```

Comment: So `for` statement only hiding the problem? Or can I use it normally if it works?

Comment: @krzakov It depends; if all you're doing is altering existing elements (without adding/removing), then it should be alright. Where is the exception actually being thrown?

Comment: But `Iterator` does not provide modification on objects. First `for` throwing me an exception. Notice that I do not remove any objects in this particular part of the code but modifying variables. I still dont know what is whrong with this code, not a single remove operation is performed.

Comment: @krzakov The concurrent modification exception is only thrown when the list itself is being modified. Modifying the objects that are contained within the list will have no effect. So somewhere in your loop you are modifying the structure of the list. Note that this can be either a remove, add or set operation.

Comment: Thing is **I do not** modify structure of the list. Maybe another thread doing it but that's why I use semaphores.

Comment: You had right, I found adding function.I missed it. I'm terribly sorry.

Comment: @krzakov No problem at all; glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

While some [existing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3184937/21441) may explain what you can do to make your code functional, they fall short of explaining exactly what's going wrong, and why.

In particular, `foreach` syntax makes use of an iterator via [`ArrayList#iterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#iterator()), and the [docs for ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) say:

> The iterators returned by this class's [`iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#iterator()) and [`listIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#listIterator(int)) methods are *fail-fast*: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own [`remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#remove()) or [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#remove()) methods, the iterator will throw a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html). Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

Comment: Is it recommended using in similar situations classic `for` statement?