# Remove element from ArrayList internally

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have the following code:

```
class Action {

    public void step(Game game) {
        //if some condition met, 
        // then remove self from action stack
        game.actionStack.remove(this);

}


class Game (

    public ArrayList<Action> actionStack;

    public Game() {
        actionStack = new Arraylist<Action>();
        actionStack.add(new Action());

        while (true) {
            for (Action action : this.actionStack) {
                action.step(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An exception gets thrown when `game.actionStack.remove(this);` occurs. Is there a way to remove the element safely from inside the `Action` class like I want?

Comment: concurrentModificationException

Comment: If you try to remove element from array, you may get `ConcurrentModificationException `. You need to use `Iterator` remove for this

Comment: possible duplicate of [ConcurrentModificationException for ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184883/concurrentmodificationexception-for-arraylist)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you're getting a ConcurrentModificationException because you're calling the list remove method while iterating it. You can't do that.

An easy fix is to work on a copy of the array when iterating:

```
for (Action action : new ArrayList<>(this.actionStack)) {
    action.step(this);
}
```

A slightly more efficient fix is to use an explicit Iterator and call its remove method. Perhaps have `step()` return a boolean indicating whether it wants to remain in the list for the next step or not:

```
for (Iterator<Action> it = this.actionStack.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Action action = it.next();
    if (!action.step(this)) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From : [the java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html) we get the following:

> **Iterators**
>
> ...
>
> Note that `Iterator.remove` is the only safe way to modify a collection during iteration; the behavior is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified in any other way while the iteration is in progress.
>
> Use `Iterator` instead of the `for-each` construct when you need to:
>
> - Remove the current element. The `for-each` construct hides the iterator, so you cannot call `remove`. Therefore, the `for-each` construct is not usable for filtering.
> - Iterate over multiple collections in parallel.
>
> The following method shows you how to use an `Iterator` to filter an arbitrary `Collection` — that is, traverse the collection removing specific elements.

```
static void filter(Collection<?> c) {
    for (Iterator<?> it = c.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
        if (!cond(it.next()))
            it.remove();
}
```

> This simple piece of code is polymorphic, which means that it works for any `Collection` regardless of implementation. This example demonstrates how easy it is to write a polymorphic algorithm using the Java Collections Framework.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I assume, you implemented `equals` and `hashCode` methods for your class 
You need to use iterator to remove like below;

```
class Game (

    public ArrayList<Action> actionStack;

    public Game() {
        actionStack = new Arraylist<Action>();
        actionStack.add(new Action());

        while (true) {
            for (Iterator<Action> it = this.actionStack.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
               it.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** step function is doing simple remove job. I move it to `Game` constructor

Comment: This won't work because you're still concurrently modifying the list. You have to remove the element through the *same* iterator as is used in the main loop.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are getting a Concurrent Modification Exception. I would suggest you do it like this

```
class Action {

    public void step(Game game) {
        //if some condition met, 
        // then remove self from action stack
        List<Action> tmpActionList = new List<Action>();
        tmpActionList = game.actionStack
        tmpActionList.remove(this);
        game.actionStack = tmpActionList;
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: This won't work because tmpActionList is not a copy. It's a pointer to the same list object.