# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException Not list remove error

Tags: java, lwjgl

```
private ArrayList<GameObject> objects;
    private ArrayList<GameObject> remove;

    private static ArrayList<GameObject> battleObjects;

    private Player player;

    private static int gameState;

    public Game() {
        gameState = OVERWORLD;

        objects = new ArrayList<GameObject>();
        remove = new ArrayList<GameObject>();

        battleObjects = new ArrayList<GameObject>();

        player = new Player(Display.getWidth() / 2 - player.SIZE / 2, Display.getHeight() / 2 - player.SIZE / 2);

        objects.add(player);
        objects.add(new Circle(32, 32, player));
        objects.add(new Imp(300, 100, player));
    }

    public void getInput() {
        player.getInput();
    }

    public void update() {
        if (gameState == BATTLE) {
            for (GameObject i : battleObjects) { //**Error happening here**
                if (!i.isRemoved())
                    i.update();
                else
                    remove.add(i);
            }
        }
        else {
            for (GameObject i : objects) {
                if (!i.isRemoved())
                    i.update();
                else
                    remove.add(i);
            }
        }

        for (GameObject i : remove)
            battleObjects.remove(i);
    }
```

Its not a list removal problem because I'm using another list to remove objects later in code not in the same for each loop. I'm not quite sure why this has happened. I have checked other threads and it doesn't seem to help my situation.

Comment: use iterator. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184883/concurrentmodificationexception-for-arraylist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new `ArrayList` and adding elements to be removed from 1st list to this list. But you must understand when you define a `array` or `List` you merely define or declares references of that type. Since you are adding elements of first List to the other(**shallow copy**), both Lists will have elements pointing to same instance internally. So no matter if you iterate on one and remove from other same internal `Collection` gets modified and hence you get the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

So now you can either create `Iterator` of the `List`, iterate and remove or you can do

```
battleObjects.removeAll(remove);
```

Comment: See the bottom part of the answer.

Comment: what boolean value does it return?

Comment: Well the GameObject class has other subclasses and I have a function that adds two GameObjects that are apart of the objects list to the battleList. Maybe that help answer the question? I know its kind of what your saying but I cant quite figure out a way to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

you can't remove an element of a collection when you are iterating on it(while iteration),
create second collection and copy each element you want on it .

Update :
second way

you should use iteration lik this

```
    ArrayList<Integer> objects = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Iterator<Integer> itr = objects.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(itr.next());
        itr.remove();
    }
```

Comment: who said this? You can definitely remove elements while iterating. Only you have to use iterators remove() method rather than of that Collection.