# What cause java.util.concurrentmodificationexception using Collections.synchronizedList?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have the following code which gives a java.util.concurrentmodificationexception.

I'm not an expert working with threads, but I thought that if I have a synchronized list, it should be thread safe...

EDIT:
This is the full code of my method.

```
@Override
    protected List< ExportSchedule > export( List< ExportSchedule > exportSchedules )
    {
        final HandleSystemDoiAdministrator handleSystemDoiAdministrator = HandleSystemDoiAdministratorFactory.getInstance();
        final List< ExportSchedule > successfullyExported = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<ExportError> unsuccessfullyExported = Collections.synchronizedList( new ArrayList<ExportError>() );

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 10 );

        for ( final ExportSchedule exportSchedule : exportSchedules )
        {
            executorService.execute( new Runnable() {
                public void run()
                {
                    String doi = exportSchedule.getDoi().getDoi();
                    String url = exportSchedule.getDoi().getUrl();

                    boolean success = handleSystemDoiAdministrator.updateDoiHandle( doi, url );

                    if ( success )
                    {
                        successfullyExported.add( exportSchedule );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if ( handleSystemDoiAdministrator.isWarn() )
                        {
                            DoiErrorHelper.persistExportError(
                                ExportInterface.HANDLE_SERVER,
                                doi,
                                "Warning: Error exporting DOI " + doi + " with URL " + url + " to Handle Server: "
                                        + handleSystemDoiAdministrator.getResponseOutcome().toString(),
                                exportSchedule.getDoi().getDoiPool() );
                        }
                        if ( handleSystemDoiAdministrator.isFatal() )
                        {


                            synchronized(unsuccessfullyExported) {
                            unsuccessfullyExported.add( DoiErrorHelper.createExportError( doi, "Fatal: Error exporting DOI " + doi + " with URL " + url + " to Handle Server: "
                                        + handleSystemDoiAdministrator.getResponseOutcome().toString(), null, new Date(), exportSchedule.getDoi().getDoiPool().getName(),
                                        exportSchedule.getDoi().getDoiPool().getDoiPrefix(), ExportInterface.HANDLE_SERVER ) );}
                        }
                    }
                }
            } );
        }

        executorService.shutdown();
        try
        {
            executorService.awaitTermination( 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES );
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e )
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return successfullyExported;
    }
```

EDIT 2:

This is the error:

```
    [exec]
     [exec] [#|2014-05-08T10:16:12.951+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=203;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:894)|
#]
     [exec]
     [exec] [#|2014-05-08T10:16:12.951+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=203;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:934)|#]
     [exec]
     [exec] [#|2014-05-08T10:16:12.951+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=203;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:932)|#]
     [exec]
     [exec] [#|2014-05-08T10:16:12.952+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=203;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at java.util.AbstractMap.toString(AbstractMap.java:518)|#]
     [exec]
     [exec] [#|2014-05-08T10:16:12.952+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=203;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at ch.ethz.id.wai.doi.export.handle.DoiExport2HSProcessing$1.r
un(DoiExport2HSProcessing.java:106)|#]
     [exec]
     [exec] [#|2014-05-08T10:16:12.952+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=203;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoo
lExecutor.java:1145)|#]
     [exec]
     [exec] [#|2014-05-08T10:16:12.952+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=203;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPo
olExecutor.java:615)|#]
     [exec]
     [exec] [#|2014-05-08T10:16:12.953+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=203;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)|#]
     [exec]
     [exec] [#|2014-05-08T10:16:28.552+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=157;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|0|#]
     [exec]
     [exec] [#|2014-05-08T10:16:31.221+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=222;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception in thread "pool-41-thread-10" |#]
     [exec]
     [exec] [#|2014-05-08T10:16:31.223+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=222;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
     [exec]     at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:894)
     [exec]     at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:934)
     [exec]     at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:932)
     [exec]     at java.util.AbstractMap.toString(AbstractMap.java:518)
     [exec]     at ch.ethz.id.wai.doi.export.handle.DoiExport2HSProcessing$1.run(DoiExport2HSProcessing.java:106)
     [exec]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
     [exec]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
     [exec]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
     [exec] |#]
```

DoiExport2HSProcessing.java is the class containing the method and line 106 is where I add the error to the list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ConcurrentModificationException for ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184883/concurrentmodificationexception-for-arraylist)

Comment: Are you sure this is an accurate summary of your code, and that there's nothing else using either `exportSchedules` or `unsuccessfullyExported` at the same time?

Comment: @Boann I edited my question with the full code of my method. As you can see, there is nothing else that uses the two lists

Comment: Looking at the stack trace it seems that `concurrentmodificationexception` is happening on a `map` and not `list`. The code u shown doesnt have use any `maps`

Comment: Only one instance of `handleSystemDoiAdministrator` is used by all threads which implies everything in there should be thread-safe too.

Answer (score 3):

`ConcurrentModificationException` has nothing to do with synchronized or thread safety directly. Multiple threads will make the condition for this exception (see below) invisible but it can also occur with one thread!

The synchronized list prevents you from accessing the list from multiple threads in an undefined state. But you still can iterate the elements while modifying the list. This will result in an `ConcurrentModificationException`.

You **must not modify** the list using `add()`, `remove()` etc. during iterating it. The only valid modifications are using methods of the  `Iterator` (`remove()`) or `ListIterator` (`add()` and `set()`)!

Comment: The first statement is incorrect. Collection that has been modified by other thread will throw CME while being iterated over.

Comment: You do not have, but this exception also occurs when other thread does modify. Can you please correct your post so the readers won't get confused?

Answer (score 1):

You have not synchronized the third list, `successfullyExported`.

That can't explain the exception from modifying `unsuccessfullyExported`, but I don't believe that's really happening. It can't be. Perhaps what's really happening is the DoiPool or HandleSystemDoiAdministrator (whatever they are) are also not synchronized.

Comment: At the moment `success` is always false, so that the fact that `successfullyExported` is not synch. is not relevant(thought later it will be :) ). Regarding DoiPool and HandleSystemDoiAdministrator, see that they are "simple" objects and I'm only reading them (without modifying them), shouldn't this be no problem?

Comment: @Francesco If that's true then you cannot possibly be getting an exception.

Comment: This is what I thought too ;), but I get the error in the question (added)

Comment: @Francesco Thanks. It's as I thought. You get the ConcurrentModificationException due to unsynchronized use of a shared **HashMap** in HandleSystemDoiAdministrator. I'm guessing it's the "response outcome", being simultaneously filled by `updateDoiHandle()` and iterated by the `toString()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29):

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it.

Maybe what you really need is a [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) instead?

**Edit:** Sorry, was a bit quick on the trigger. After careful examination of the code in question, and since the `ConcurrentModificationException` happens on an `AbstractMap` call to `toString()` and there is only one explicit call to `toString()` and the only place that actively seems to mutate state is this `handleSystemDoiAdministrator.updateDoiHandle( doi, url );` line, I'm thinking the underlying cause is probably hidden somewhere inside that Class. As it seems to be a Singleton being used by many threads at once. I would check to make sure that it was threadsafe first.

Comment: He's not iterating the synchronized list though?

Comment: @Boann Whoops. I have corrected my answer to maybe be more helpful. :)

Comment: This is basically what I said [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536074/what-cause-java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-using-collections-synchroni/23536228?noredirect=1#comment36108929_23536815)

Comment: Then it's probably pretty accurate, huh? :)