# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException occurs in the program

Tags: java, arraylist, concurrentmodification

I am trying to copy a limited number of elements from `List<Integer> data` being passed from the main method, into another `List<Integer> remainder`. When I debug the program and run the code lines step by step, there's no error. But when I try to run the code normally I get the `ConcurrentModificationError`. I've looked upon other SO threads and I was unable to solve it.

```
public static List<Integer> calculate_remainder(List<Integer> data, int[] polynomial, List<Integer> append)
{
    List<Integer> remainder = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<Integer> data_iterator = data.iterator();

    data = Main.append(data, append);

    for (int i = 0; i < polynomial.length; i++)
    {
        if (data_iterator.hasNext())
        {
            remainder.add(data_iterator.next());
        }
    }
```

Update 1:

```
public static List<Integer> append(List<Integer> data, List<Integer> append)
{
    data.addAll(append);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: What does Main.append do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ConcurrentModificationException for ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184883/concurrentmodificationexception-for-arraylist)

Comment: @twinklehawk just appends another list to data list.

Comment: can you post the stack trace? this method is really strange. why do you iterate over the polynomial length but only operate using the data_iterator?

Comment: Maybe getting the iterator after calling `Main.append`

Comment: Yeup! The answer by @twinklehawk worked. I was modifying the list in the append method. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Iterator` throws `ConcurrentModificationException` when the underlying list has been changed after the `Iterator` is created (search for fail-fast in [ArrayList JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)).
 Try moving the creation of the `Iterator` to after the `Main.append` call.

Answer (score 0):

Iterator is created to traverse a collection and once it is created, it checks for
modification every time it is used and in case of modification it throws ConcurrentModificationException when it tries to access the collection again.
And as twinklehawk said, you need to create the iterator after you are done appending..