# How should I go about cloning a nest ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, nested, bluej, cloning

I need to write out a method to clone a nested `ArrayList`.

The nested `ArrayList` looks like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Ship>> theSea = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Ship>>();
```

I want to copy it to a clone:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Ship>> seaClone = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Ship>>();
```

I've tried iterating it and copying over the lists:

```
for(int i = 0; i < theSea.size(); i++){
    seaClone.add(theSea.get(i));
}
```

However, this doesn't clone the elements of the nested `ArrayList<Ship>` and instead just copies over a reference to it.

How should I go about cloning the elements of the nested `ArrayList<Ship>`?

Comment: how does your `Ship` class look like?

Comment: You need two loops, one iterating over the outer `List`, one iterating over the inner `List`s. And don't use `clone()` and `Cloneable` [since it is broken](https://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html).

Comment: You could override the clone method in you class `Ship` (deep copy). Then write a function to make a deep copy of a ArrayList `for(Ship s : oldList) newLidt.add(s.copy());`. Now you should call this written method for all ArrayList row...

Comment: @0x1C1B you could use `clone()`, but you shouldn't. See the link in my previous comment.

Comment: @Brian why not try it out?

Comment: @Turing85 would the code look something like this:

`for(int i = 0 ; i<theSea.size(); i++){
            boardClone.add(theSea.get(i));
            for(ShipInterface s : theSea.get(i)){
                boardClone.get(i).add(s);
            }
        }`

Comment: @Brian again... why not try it out? I will not look at code you post in the comments.

Comment: @Turing85 I get the ConcurrentModificationException. I tried splitting up the `for` loop so that I first add the lists to seaClone then add the elements of theSea.get().get(). My issue now lies in how to iterate over theSea without concurrently modifying it?

Comment: Do you need to clone `Ship`, or just the nested list?

Comment: @shmosel I need to clone every `Ship` element as well

Comment: @Brian [Please do your research.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184883/concurrentmodificationexception-for-arraylist)

Answer (score 0):

> However, this doesn't clone the elements of the nested ArrayList
>   and instead just copies over a reference to it.

Because it is actually what you are doing : you add the reference of the existing objects in the new List.
So instead of, create a new nested ArrayList for each cloned sublist and create new Ship objects as you add elements in the new `List`s.
You could define a copy constructor in `Ship` for example :

```
public Ship(Ship model){     
  foo = model.foo;
  bar = model.bar;    
}
```

You can so write :

```
for(List<Ship> list : theSea){
    List<Ship> currentList = new ArrayList<>();
     for(Ship ship : list){
        currentList.add(new Ship(ship));
     }
    clone.add(currentList);
  }
```

Comment: `theSea` is an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Ship>>`, thus `theSea.get(i)` will return an `ArrayList<Ship>`.

Comment: The constructor is invalid java

Comment: It is really not my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Ship` objects are cloneable:

```
List<List<Ship>> clone = theSea.stream()
    .map(l -> l.stream().map(s -> (Ship)s.clone()).collect(toList()))
    .collect(toList());
```

Comment: @Turing85 in your (and Bloch's) opinion. It's not mine. There are plenty of situation in which it can be used safely.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Ship>> listCopy = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    ArrayList<Ship> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j=0; j<list.get(i).size(); j++) {
        newList.add(new Ship(list.get(i).get(j)));
    }
    listCopy.add(newList);
}
```

Observe this line: `newList.add(new Ship(list.get(i).get(j)));`

Where you need to pass the object to the constructor and from there duplicate all the attributes, otherwise you will just create a reference to the same class.

If your ship class is to complex with many other objects inside this task may be difficult and you can use a tool like serializing to json and then revert back to object or using a java deep object cloner.